# Creating a custom live distro based on Ubuntu - won't boot in SecureBoot

Tags: boot, grub2, uefi, lubuntu, live-usb

I'm trying to create a custom live distro that's based on Lubuntu. I want to take standard Lubuntu, add a few customizations of my own and then create an .iso that people can download, write to a USB and run.

The way the standard Lubuntu .iso runs is what I'm after.

- Can be written in ISO mode
- Writes onto a USB as a single FAT32 partition
- Boots in BIOS, UEFI and SecureBoot

To get this, I installed Lubuntu, set up my customizations and created an .iso. To get the .iso, I'm using distroshare, a script set up several years ago that doesn't seem to be maintained. From my understanding of the script, the commands that determine how the .iso will behave are:

apt-get -q=2 install grub-efi-amd64

apt-get -q=2 install grub-pc

However, when I write this .iso out to a USB I get:

- Must be written in dd mode
- 3 partitions
- It boots in BIOS and UEFI, but not when SecureBoot is active

I'm really don't understand these things so well so I don't know why it's causing a difference:

- How do I create the .iso so that it's written out in a simpler way?
- Why can't I boot this in SecureBoot? My understanding is that all of the Ubuntu bootloaders were signed and hence bootable under SecureBoot.

**Additional Info**

I ran across this page https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UEFI/SecureBoot and I saw a reference to *grub-efi-amd64-signed*. I thought that if I used that instead of *grub-efi-amd64* I'd have better luck.

It didn't work. It will still boot on BIOS and UEFI but not if SecureBoot is in place.

Comment: You haven't said which release you are basing it on, which matters as changes to cdimages & how those images have booted have been made, meaning we don't know which method you are trying to use (and whether or not your *script* caters for these changes!)... FYI: You're trying to create what is usually called a *respin* rather than a distro

Comment: @guiverc  I'm basing everything off of the latest version, Lubuntu 20.04.1. I'm playing with the 64 bit version. The distroshare tool that I found looks like it was last updated about 5 years ago. Is this a bad choice, and should I try to find something else?

Answer (score 0):

there are better options to create a own base image. On former Ubuntu dists you could use a technic called preseeding, but afaik this can't deal with UEFI.

The much simplear way is to use FAI ([Fully Automated Installation](https://wiki.fai-project.org/index.php/Main_Page)). It's in use for the debian based Distro GRML.

Comment: I'm trying to read the documentation for this tool and am getting a bit confused. Will it allow me to customize a system and then create an .iso from it so that I can put it on a website and have others download it?